# AngularJS: get siblings when using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm working on a list(<ul>), that is used multiple times inside different ng-repeat-iterations on one page.

The first list-items are generated by ng-repeat, the (second-)last list-item contains a span, which when clicked on, should cause the last list-item(hidden on page load) to show

```
                  <ul ng-repeat="list in lists">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in getItems(a,b)">{{item}} 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="display_item_form($event)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="display: none;" class="item-form">
                      content to be shown on 'button' press
                    </li>
                  </ul>
```

Apart from passing $event, i tried passing 'this', but the result is always undefined or an exception

```
    $scope.display_item_form = function($event){
//         alert($(it).parent().siblings('.item-form').attr('type'));//passing this instead of $event: result: undefined
            alert($($event.target).attr('type')); //undefined
//         $(it).parent().parent().children('.item-form').show();
//         $('.item-form').show(); // this works, but i only want .item-form inside the current <ul> to be shown

    }
```

Comment: Seems like using a controller variable to controller this and then ng-if="variable==true" and setting the variable from ng-click would be the way to go. If you need to re-use it, move it to a directive or component.

Comment: try prop('type') instead of attr('type') because there is no type attribute set

Comment: Will you add your function for `getItems()` ?

Comment: getItems() just returns an array of list-items, there is no relation to the last 2 list-items apart from their parents, prop('type') is still undefined, i will now look into components(directives) since i dont have too much experience with angular

Comment: @tzimme I was just using it to build my response correctly. In my answer below I just made a generic array that you can replace with your actual `getItems` function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution:

angular.element();

```
$scope.display_item_form = function($evt){
    var ele = angular.element($evt.target);
    ele.parent().parent().find('.item-form').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this entirely in the HTML.

`showItem` isn't defined at first, so it won't show. Once you click the button, you toggle the button (sets it to true in this case), and it displays.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   
  $scope.list = [{ val: 1 },{ val: 2 },{ val: 3 },{ val: 4 },{ val: 5 }];

$scope.list2 = [{ val: 1 },{ val: 2 },{ val: 3 },{ val: 4 },{ val: 5 }];
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">

<div data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.val}} </li>
        <li data-ng-click="showList1Item=!showList1Item"><span style="cursor:pointer;">+</span></li>
        <li data-ng-show="showList1Item">last item</li>
    </ul>

    <ul data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list2">{{item.val}} </li>
        <li data-ng-click="showList2Item=!showList2Item"><span style="cursor:pointer;">+</span></li>
        <li data-ng-show="showList2Item">last item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: although i like it, the problem with this solution are the multiple occurences of the list, it makes all 'last' items on the page show

Comment: You can have a different variable `showItem` for different lists. Like showTest1Item, showTest2Item.

Comment: it's only this one list, being created dynamically when needed inside multiple nested ng-repeat

Comment: The last item that you want to display... is it part of the original loop? Or could it be? You could always loop through a list of everything except the last one, and then when you click, finish looping.

Comment: no, first: items from the loop are displayed. then: when clicking on + additional, but not related information is shown as well as some inputs

Comment: Hmm. I guess last ditch, you could try something with appending the list item after. Kinda along this route:

`$scope.toggleList = function ($evt) {
    
    var ele = angular.element($evt.currentTarget);
    
     ele.append("<li class='last-item'>last item</li>");
    
  };

`

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a variable on $scope upon load and reference in the last `li`'s `ng-if` statement.

Take note that : 
`ng-if` removes the conditioned element from the DOM.
`ng-show` applies `display: none;` to the conditioned element in the DOM.

this is important to remember in case you are needing to re-initialise any child components that may be inside the conditioned element.

Hope this helps! :-)

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in getItems(a,b)">{{item}}</li>
  
  <li>
    <span ng-click="$scope.showContent = true"></span>
  </li>
  
  <li ng-if="$scope.showContent">
    content to be shown on 'button' press
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unless there is a way to dynamically assign $scope.showContent to the current ul i guess this also effects all lists' 'last' items on the page

Comment: Are you not just wanting to show the last static `li`  ?